# Sorting array in 1 order by 2 keys

Tags: php

I have an array like so.

```
  [Badi Assad] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => Assad
        [first_name] => Badi
        [artist_name] => 
        [asterick] => *
        [slug] => badiassad
    )

[Ben Taylor] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => Taylor
        [first_name] => Ben
        [artist_name] => Ben Taylor
        [asterick] => *
        [slug] => bentaylor
    )

[Beverly] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => Hills
        [first_name] => Beverly
        [artist_name] => Beverly
        [asterick] => 
        [slug] => Eedih
    )

[Bruce Cockburn] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => Cockburn
        [first_name] => Bruce
        [artist_name] => Bruce Cockburn
        [asterick] => *
        [slug] => brucecockburn
    )

[Bohème] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => 
        [first_name] => Cassidy
        [artist_name] => Bohème
        [asterick] => *
        [slug] => cassidy
    )
```

How would I sort is so it it would be in order with the last name and artist name in order where the last name trumps the artist name except when it is empty.

The resulting should look like this.

```
  [Badi Assad] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => Assad
        [first_name] => Badi
        [artist_name] => 
        [asterick] => *
        [slug] => badiassad
    )
[Bohème] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => 
        [first_name] => Cassidy
        [artist_name] => Bohème
        [asterick] => *
        [slug] => cassidy
    )
[Bruce Cockburn] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => Cockburn
        [first_name] => Bruce
        [artist_name] => Bruce Cockburn
        [asterick] => *
        [slug] => brucecockburn
    )

[Beverly] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => Hills
        [first_name] => Beverly
        [artist_name] => Beverly
        [asterick] => 
        [slug] => Eedih
    )
[Ben Taylor] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => Taylor
        [first_name] => Ben
        [artist_name] => Ben Taylor
        [asterick] => *
        [slug] => bentaylor
    )
```

I am currently trying this.

```
    $newartists = array();
foreach($users as $k => $v)
 {
    $name = (strlen($v['artist_name']) > 0) ? $v['artist_name'] : $v['first_name'].' '.$v['last_name'];
    $newartists[$name]['last_name'] = $v['last_name'];
    $newartists[$name]['first_name'] = $v['first_name'];
    $newartists[$name]['artist_name'] = $v['artist_name'];
    $newartists[$name]['asterick'] = $ask;
    $newartists[$name]['slug'] = $v['slug'];
}                    
$sort = array();
foreach($newartists as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['artist_name'][$k] = $v['artist_name'];
    $sort['last_name'][$k] = $v['last_name'];
}

array_multisort( $sort['last_name'], SORT_ASC,$sort['artist_name'], SORT_ASC, $newartists);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should use [uksort][1]


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Comment: Next to the array sorting functions you also need something that works with unicode (or the encoding you use). I'm sure for the bare array sorting you find three or more good examples on this website already. After you've fiddled that, let me know if you can can't figure out with unicode based sorting in PHP.

Comment: Aaaaand what happened when you ran the code snippet above?

Comment: That gives me this. http://paste.laravel.com/oyE The first and second in the array are reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [uasort function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) somewhat like this:

```
<?php
    $newartists = array(
        '3' => array(
            'last_name'   => 'c',
            'artist_name' => 'c'
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'artist_name' => 'a'
        ),
        '2' => array(
            'last_name'   => 'b',
            'artist_name' => 'd'
        ),
    );

    function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        $result = 0;

        // Sort preferably by last name
        if (!empty($a['last_name']) && !empty($b['last_name'])) {
            $result = strcmp($a["last_name"], $b["last_name"]);

        // Failover to artist name sort
        } else {
            $result = strcmp($a["artist_name"], $b["artist_name"]);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    usort($newartists, "cmp");
```

#### Result

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [artist_name] => a
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [last_name] => b
            [artist_name] => d
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [last_name] => c
            [artist_name] => c
        )
)
```